# Redirect Server ports from behind a firewall via ssh tunnel to another via dyndns reachable server

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, tunnel, dyndns

my setting is as follows:

server1 is behind a firewall. its running a service on port X.

server2 is an already dyndns reachable homeserver, lets say "mydomain.com"

i am trying to forward (via ssh reverse tunneling) port X to server2, so that anyone can access the service originally provided on server1 through simply connecting to "mydomain.com:X" with the related app.

my steps so far were:

**1.** establish ssh reverse tunnel on server1

```
ssh -p22 $nokey $keepalive -nNT -R "*:$PortX:localhost:$PortX" sshuser@$dyndnsIP"
```

--> tunnel is okay as far as i am can tell, its present on server2 (tested via netstat -tlpn)

**2.** now established portforwarding on homeDSLModemRouter from PortX to server2:PortX (used internal ip here, no error here)

**3.** now trying to connect via app to "mydomain.com:PortX" - no success.

**Am i missing something vital?** help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: EDIT - FOUND THE SOLUTION
server2 had an update which resetted the necessary option for the whole thing; The cfg-file "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" should be changed to "GatewayPorts yes", then the whole thing works.

Conclusion: With this method, you can access any server-services from different sites - you only need to reversetunnel them to one single dyndns client which is reachable for the public. 

Furthermore, there is no need to bother the admins at the deployment site in opening ports for your server - but please keep in mind to ask them for permission before!

Nice result.

Answer (score 0):

Answer - jst read my Comment above.

It was necessary to set "GatewayPorts yes" in the public reachable dyndns-Server2.